# LaTeX more "basic" commands

Tags: environments, package-writing

Currently learning how to write packages & define custom environments.

In many examples I come across unfamiliar commands (such as `\oalign`). I so far have had no luck
finding their meaning online.

Is there any online guide/repository that has the meaning of all of these commands written down?

Comment: Consider reading [The TeX Book](https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Extra/D._Knuth-The_TeXbook.pdf) and [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic). You know, as bed-time reading.

Comment: Related: [What are good resources for a beginner, non-computer genius type of person, to learn Plain TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299858/5764); [Electronic version of Knuth's “TeXbook”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110836/5764)

Comment: Search this site for such things.  I find usage examples to be an excellent teacher.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of the code is undocumented. For LaTeX internals, `texdoc source2e` is your friend¹. For TeX primitives, *The TeXbook* is an indispensable guide although there are other excellent books available for free online (as mentioned in the comments). Perhaps the most comprehensive account of TeX's internals is Stefan v. Bechtolsheim's four-volume magnum opus, *TeX in Practice*, although it can be hard to find reasonably priced copies.

Your choice of `\oalign` is especially notable since this is defined in plain TeX, but only mentioned in the appendix³ where plain.tex is listed in its entirety with some commentary, but not a whole lot. In this instance, `\oalign` is used to build stacked characters for things like the accents `\d` (ạ) and `\b` (ḵ) as well as the copyright symbol ©. The only real ``documentation'' of it is in its usage—see lines 679–690 of `plain.tex`.

Here's a somewhat modified and abridged version of that section to show how it's used:

```
\def\oalign#1{%
  \leavevmode % ❶
  \vtop{% ❷
    \baselineskip=0pt% ❸
    \lineskip.25ex% ❸
    \ialign{##\crcr#1\crcr}% ❹
  }%
} 
\def\o@lign{%
   \lineskiplimit=0pt% ❸
   \oalign % ❺
}
\def\d#1{%
  {%
    \o@lign{%
      \relax#1\crcr % ❻
      \hidewidth\sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth % ❼
    }%
  }%
}
```

The first thing `\oalign` does is make sure that it's in horizontal mode ❶. In TeX, if you aren't in the middle of a paragraph and you have a box (whether it's an `\hbox` or `\vbox` or `\vtop` or even an `\halign`, the box will be added to the vertical list instead of starting a new paragraph. `\leavevmode` starts a new paragraph if we're not already in a paragraph and does nothing if we are.

`\vtop` ❷ is a vertical box (so it can contain multiple lines) but unlike its close cousin `\vbox` the baseline of the box will be the baseline of the first line in the box (with `\vbox` the baseline of the box will be the baseline of the *last* line in the box).

Then we have a bunch of magic for setting the line skip (cf the lines marked ❸). The spacing between lines is based on three parameters: `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit`. Most of the time, the skip from one baseline to another will be `\baselineskip`⁴. But, if the distance from the top of one line to the bottom of the next is smaller than `\lineskiplimit`, then `\lineskip` of extra space will be added.⁵ This is the mechanism that keeps lines of text with super- and subscripts from colliding with each other. The settings here effectively let the characters be printed stacked up with just .25ex of space separating them.⁶

`\ialign` ❹ is a variation of the primitive `\halign` for defining tables. It makes sure that `\tabskip` is 0pt. In this instance, the align is just for stacking up the contents. The `\crcr` functions similarly to `\\` in a LaTeX table for separating lines.⁷ The `##\crcr` at the beginning sets a template for the table where the `##` stands for the contents of a cell. In this case, we're saying we have a single-column table with no formatting around its contents.

The call to `\oalign` at the end of the macro ❺ is a common shortcut you'll see in TeX macro definitions. DEK could have defined `\o@lign` as

```
\def\o@lign#1{...\oalign{#1}}
```

but this approach avoids having to copy the argument twice.⁸

The definition of `\d` lets us see how the underdot is actually set. We call `\o@lign`⁹ and give it two lines for the alignment: the first ❻ is just the letter we're putting a dot under. The second is the actual dot. The second ❼ sets the underdot. The pair `\hidewidth`…`\hidewidth` centers the dot, but allows it to stick out of space reserved for it if necessary.¹⁰ The `\sh@ft` is there to adjust the position of the character if it appears in italics so that, e.g., *ạ* will have the correct positioning of the underdot.

---

1. From a command line on a computer with TeX and friends installed you can type `texdoc xxx` where `xxx` is some package name and get the documentation on the package. In some instances, the documentation includes annotated source code. `source2e` is the annotated source code² of the LaTeX kernel.
2. It is, however, very much a work in progress and has been for nearly 30 years. There are sections where the documentation is just the original 2.09 comments which in some cases may be out of date. Other old bits are undocumented or underdocumented. In some cases, the *why* of some of the code may be lost to the mists of time.
3. It's sufficiently obscure that my first thought when I saw it was, oh, he must have mistyped `\noalign`.
4. Good name.
5. The default values are 0pt for `\lineskiplimit` and 1pt for `\lineskip`.
6. A definition that I left out for `\ooalign` sets `\lineskiplimit` to `-\maxdimen`, so that the lines will overlap entirely.
7. This is an oversimplification, much like saying that there are 365 days in a year, but it will do for this discussion.
8. Philosophically, I like to think of it as a relative to tail-call optimization. After years programming TeX, things like TCO were trivial to conceptualize when I first encountered them.
9. I'm a bit mystified as to why DEK decided that he would enclose all the calls to `\o@lign` with braces rather than incorporate the braces into the definition of `\o@lign`. Not only are all calls executed inside a group, but it is potentially hazardous for them to occur *outside* a group. ‍♂️
10. It's difficult to conceive of that happening with the dot of `\d`, but the similarly defined `\b` which uses the macron diacritical (¯) positioned below could conceivably be wider than the character it goes beneath. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_below), ḻ is used in transcribed Tamil and Seri and proposed for Mapudungun.